# How to add a text/string in-between two matching texts using awk/sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

```
In Below file.

nsswitch.conf

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis sss ldap
sudoers: files sss

i want to add text 'ldap' in last line between 'files' and 'sss' which should give an output file as below 

nsswitch.conf

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis sss ldap
sudoers: files ldap sss
```

right now I am changing the line using sed.

```
sed -i '/sudoers: files sss/c sudoers: files ldap sss' nsswitch.conf
```

Is there any better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Define "better". What aspect of your current solution is not as good as you wish?

Comment: i have other files also where such editing is required and replacing every line does not seem right to me. for e.g if i want to add ldap in more than one line in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution would be

```
awk '$1 ~ /sudoers/ && $0 !~/ldap/ { $2 = $2 " ldap" ;} {print ;} ' nsswitch.conf > nsswith.txt
cp nsswith.txt nsswith.conf
```

where

- `$1 ~ /sudoers/ && $0 !~/ldap/` select line starting with sudoers, not having ldap
- `{ $2 = $2 " ldap" ;}` insert ldap in third position
- `{print ;}` print the line (modified line and other line as well)

please note :

- that as a rule `awk` can't do inline editing, you have to relay on a temporary file.
- awk solution can handle space problem. (e.g. if one or more space or tab between `sudoers:` and `file` )